# How to transform byte-like string into str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string like this:

```
b'\nArtist\xc2\xa0ID\nGTS-077223438\nJInstrument\xc2\xa0type\nUkulele\nWork\xc2\xa0country\nSpain\n'
```

Original was encoded in "utf-8"

My question is: how do i transform this byte-like into string "as is"? I mean, keeping the b' , \xc2, \n...

If I use str.decode("utf-8") I loose most of the stuff.

Comment: Have you tried `str(string)` or `repr(string)`?

Comment: What  do you mean  by *you lose most of the stuff*? If you want to keep the bytes string why are you decoding?

Comment: repr(string) worked here. thanks @vaultah
PadraicCunningham most of the stuff is \n, \xa0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `repr(string)` - that's exactly how the string with 'b' prefix and escape sequences is created.